# QTextEdit doesn't display special characters not available on keyboard

Tags: c++, qt, qt4

I have to display some special characters like ¼, ½ etc. in a QTextEdit which are not on the QWERTY keyboard.I am able to type these characters in the QTextEdit and also able to paste them. But when I try to programatically set these characters QTextEdit displays an extra character 'Â'.

I do not get this problem while typing and pasting.  These characters are typed with some Alt+[code] codes.

I am using Qt 4.8 on Windows 8 64bit.

```
#include<QtGui>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
 QApplication a(argc, argv);
QTextEdit t;
    t.setPlainText("¼2½  \n");              // QTextEdit displays=> Â¼2Â½
    //    t.setHtml("¼2½  \n");             // QTextEdit displays=> Â¼2Â½
    //    t.insertHtml("¼2½  \n");          // QTextEdit displays=> Â¼2Â½
    //    t.insertPlainText("¼2½  \n");     // QTextEdit displays=> Â¼2Â½
// also tried setHtml() with HTML code which works in Firefox didn't help me 
    t.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

How can I put these characters in a QTextEdit programatically without this extra character?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use QTextCodec to display characters in UTF-8 encoding.

```
#include <QTextCodec>
...
QTextCodec* codec=QTextCodec::codecForName("UTF-8");
//    QTextCodec::setCodecForLocale(codec); //if you want everything to be in UTF-8
QTextCodec::setCodecForCStrings(codec);
QApplication a(argc, argv);
...
```

Or convert characters in place:

```
t.setPlainText(QObject::trUtf8("¼2½  \n"));
```

Comment: will it work throughout the application? How QTextCodec is related to QTextEdit? I mean don't we need a setter() function on QTextEdit/QApplication.

Comment: I edited my ansver. Yes, it will work globally. QTextCodec sets encoding for entire application, so it should be set in main(). Alternatively, see the second part of my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Your source code needs to be written in UTF-8 encoding, and you should use `QStringLiteral` in Qt 5 or `QString::fromUtf8` in Qt 4. You won't have that problem then.

E.g.:

```
t.setPlainText(QStringLiteral("¼, ½"));    // Qt 5
t.setPlainText(QString::fromUtf8("¼, ½")); // Qt 4
```

Ensure that the editor you're using is set to encode the file as UTF-8, not Latin 1 etc.